# EF Core query seems not to detect DB changes while polling a table

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a job composed by several step, some of them are external batches triggered by inserting a record in a specific table, and the only way to know whether the batch finished or not, and with which result, is to poll the table.
I made this with a do...while loop, like this:

```
do
{
    if (requestCount > maxRequestAttempts)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Max attempts ({requestCount}) reached for batch [{batchName}], job stopped.");

    checkResponse = _batchService.CheckBatchStatus(checkRequest);
    _logger.LogDebug($"Check Batch status #{requestCount} of {maxRequestAttempts}, result: {checkResponse.ToJson()}");

        requestCount++;

    if (checkResponse.Batch.IsSucceded == false && checkResponse.Batch.IsFaulted == false)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ts);
} while (checkResponse.Success && (checkResponse.Batch.IsSucceded == false && checkResponse.Batch.IsFaulted == false));
```

And, behind the scene, I composed a raw sql statement used as a parameter by .FromSql EF method:

```
    const string paramId = "FILEID";

sb.AppendLine("SELECT * ")
  .AppendLine("FROM [Table] t ")
  .AppendFormat("WHERE CAST(t.[XMLPAR] as XML).exist('/PARAMETERS/PARAM[@ID=\"{0}\" and @VALUE=\"{1}\"]') = 1 ", paramId.ToUpperInvariant(), fileId.ToString().ToUpperInvariant())
  .AppendLine("AND t.BatchName = @batchName");

string rawSql = sb.ToString();
using (Context ctx = new Context())
{
    List<Entity21> result = ctx.Entity21.FromSql(rawSql, parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
    var response = result.FirstOrDefault();

    return response;
}
```

The problem is that, after the batch ended with a result (I know it through the same query ran from SS Management Studio), the query executed from EF seems not to detect the record changes, or it detects them only very late in time and in a randomly manner.
Any known reason that can explain such a behaviour? Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where the changes made in an uncommitted transaction? EF uses read committed transactions by default.

Comment: It's going to  be really difficult to say without knowing anything more about the model, the query, or about how the process updates the database to indicate its progress. Based on your second code snippet, if I were to make a wild guess, I would say to make sure that your list of `Entity21` is sorted in such a way that the "finished" record is the first one in the list.

Comment: `Any known reason` application bugs, orphaned transactions, inappropriate queries. The question *doesn't* show any queries so it's impossible to guess what exactly is wrong. What does `rawSql` contain? Who writes to that table, who reads from it?

Comment: @DannyVarod It's a single, isolated read operation, so I didn't wrap it in a transaction...should I?

Comment: @epros is it? And what does the query actually do? What you posted can return *multiple* results, but you only return one of them. You're asking us to guess, or rather, reverse engineer your code from the error description

Comment: Sorry for missing information, I edit my question including the query. FileId is a Guid, unique in the table.